# How to shorten notation for vector

Tags: r

I would like to create a vector and here is my code:

```
x <- c(-1071, -1072, -1073, -1074, -1075, -1074, -1073, -1072, -1071)
```

May I know how to do it in a shortened notation?

Comment: x <- c(-1071:-1075, -1074:-1071)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we want a declining sequence with initial step size -1 that reverses half way and that the inputs are the sequence length, n, and the first element, a, we have:

```
n <- 9 # number of elements
a <- -1071 # first element

p <- seq(a, length = n, by = -1)
pmax(p, rev(p))
## [1] -1071 -1072 -1073 -1074 -1075 -1074 -1073 -1072 -1071
```

If the inputs are the maximum and minimum elements where the first element is the maximum then:

```
a <- -1071 # max / first
b <- -1075 # min

c(a:b, (b:a)[-1])
## [1] -1071 -1072 -1073 -1074 -1075 -1074 -1073 -1072 -1071
```